# How can I get if checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

I'm trying to get checkbox's checked Attribute.I try using `GeckoHtmlElement`'s
 `GetAttribute()` function but it always returns null value for `checked` Attribute.

I try this:

```
Gecko.GeckoElementCollection z = Browser.Document.GetElementsByName("productBox[]");
foreach (Gecko.GeckoNode o in z)
{
   if (o.NodeType == NodeType.Element)
   {
      GeckoHtmlElement asd = (GeckoHtmlElement)o;
      string aa =asd.GetAttribute("checked");
      if (aa != null && aa == "True")
          liaaa.Add(o);
   }
}
```

checkBoxes's Html:

```
<input name="productBox[]" value="10914" class="noborder" type="checkbox">
```

I try this but still not working. This returns a Null Gecko Node :

```
string aa =asd.Attributes["checked"];
```

**UPDATE:**
I completed my work but my way is uggly ,dirty and less usable.In browsers `DomMouseUp` event :

```
GeckoElement active = (GeckoElement)browser.Document.ActiveElement;
if (active.Attributes["name"].TextContent == "productBox[]")
{
   if (getHtmlelement(active).Parent.GetAttribute("style") == null ||
       getHtmlelement(active).GetAttribute("style") == "")
   {
      getHtmlelement(active).SetAttribute("style", "MyCheck");
      liaaa.Add(active);
   }
   else
   {
      getHtmlelement(active).SetAttribute("style", "");
      liaaa.Remove(active);
   }
}
```

It's working for now because all checkboxes are not checked by default when page loads.But a better way can help a lot.

Thanks

Comment: If checkbox tag contains _checked_ attribute then what happens ? _<input name="productBox[]" value="10914" class="noborder" type="checkbox" checked>_ ?

Comment: @Coder It returns "checked" but only if the checkbox checked by default html.And if I check it like `asd.SetAttribute("checked","checked");` its beeng checked but still `GetAttribute` returns null for `checked` attribute.But `GetAttribute` works fine on other attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting to a GeckoInputElement will give you access to the Checked property:

```
if (o.NodeType == NodeType.Element && o is GeckoInputElement)
{
      GeckoInputElement asd = (GeckoInputElement)o;
      if (asd.Checked)
        ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string aa =asd.Attributes["checked"];
```

Comment: `asd.Attributes["checked"];` Returns a  `GeckoNode` not a string and the `GeckoNode` is null.